Can't change the legend position in R
I am generating this chart using this code in R.
ggplotly(
 gplot(data=ComercioLineChart,aes(x=ComercioLineChart$Ano,y=ComercioLineChart$`Quantidade (L)`,color=ComercioLineChart$Categoria)) +
    geom_line(alpha = .5) + 
    geom_point(alpha = .5) +
    labs(title = "Comércio de categorias de vinhos por ano",subtitle = "1970-2016",caption = "Dados obtidos em: http://vitibrasil.cnpuv.embrapa.br/index.php?opcao=opt_01", y = "Quantidade (em milhões de litros)", x = NULL, color = "Categorias") +
    scale_y_continuous(n.breaks=10, labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position ="bottom")
    )

The problem is that I simply cannot change the legend position. I've tried with numbers, "top", "bottom" etc etc etc. Nothing works.
What am I doing wrong?
I wanted the legend to be smalled and get bellow the chart, so the chart would be wider
enter image description here

plotly has native functions to position the legend:
p <- ggplotly(...)
p %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = 'h', x = 0.5, xanchor = 'center', y = -0.3))

example graph

Thank you!! that's exactly what i wanted!!! Is there a way to stack the legends in three rows of three values each?

Yes, I would view the arguments that layout can take and have fun exploring: https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/
orientation = 'h' is the argument, specifically, that turns it row-based.

Hard to tell without a reproducible example, but looks like using more than one "theme" could be part of the problem. Have you tried running the code with theme_bw() + removed?

Hi Frewtea, welcome to SO. The correct action in this instance is to either comment on the question to ask for clarification, or given you have insufficient rep, flag the question as Needs improvement > Needs details or clarity.
